# How to make Android listen to message like a server?

Tags: web-server

I need to know if Android can listen to a data sensor via wifi? Can android listen to a port and be like a server?

```
Arduino Device Sensor -> WIFI connection (protocol?) -> Android Device
```

Can Android device listen to certain port with HTTP messages?

Comment: Reading between the lines: Are you looking for some [Arduino helper app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_various#group_1035)?

Comment: @Izzy I am not sure about which Arduino Helper you are referring to.

Comment: I can't tell you which one might match as 1) I'm not familiar with Arduino (I have none) and 2) your question doesn't tell what you want to achieve. Listening to a given port is done by a server process, so you need to install the corresponding server app. Hard to say which one that would be without knowing what you want to do :) So I just gave you a link to Arduino apps in the hope you could pick the one matching your goal. As your question is currently phrased, the answer would be: "yes, with the appropriate app" :)

Comment: As of currently written, your question seems too broad/unclear. As for your specific question: yes, Android supports [socket](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) programming, but you need specific app to listen to them. Android OS by default doesn't provide such app, so sending HTTP messages to the device won't achieve any.

Comment: @AndrewT. okay. I was just concern if the port has security restrictions and if the Android operation system would allow the continuous opening of the app. By the way, does android allow a no-GUI applicaiton to receive the socket or I would need to open the application opening the listening port for it to work?

Comment: AFAIK, you can use persistent service (no-GUI) as server that always listens to client's request. I personally have done something like that using sockets for sensor monitoring from Android. However, that's outside of the scope of this site, which is more for end-users, not developer.